# Display List into Console

Tags: c#

I trying to display a `List` into Console

My List code:

```
var order = new List<Orders>();
order.Add(new Orders { Date = "" + orders[0].date_created, Name = ""+ orders[0].billing.first_name , Adress = ""+ orders[0].shipping.address_1 + "                     " + orders[0].shipping.address_2 });
order.Add(new Orders { Date = "" + orders[1].date_created, Name = "" + orders[1].billing.first_name, Adress = "" + orders[1].shipping.address_1 + "                     " + orders[1].shipping.address_2 });
order.Add(new Orders { Date = "" + orders[2].date_created, Name = "" + orders[2].billing.first_name, Adress = "" + orders[2].shipping.address_1 + "                     " + orders[2].shipping.address_2 });
order.Add(new Orders { Date = "" + orders[3].date_created, Name = "" + orders[3].billing.first_name, Adress = "" + orders[3].shipping.address_1 + "                     " + orders[3].shipping.address_2 });
order.Add(new Orders { Date = "" + orders[4].date_created, Name = "" + orders[4].billing.first_name, Adress = "" + orders[4].shipping.address_1 + "                     " + orders[4].shipping.address_2 });

return order;
```

I have tried to display it like this:

```
Debug.WriteLine(order.ToString());
```

and like this:

```
order.ForEach(i => Debug.WriteLine(i.ToString()));
```

But gives the warning:

> Unreachable code

How I can display the list?

Comment: The "Unreachable code" warning tells me that you've put your `Debug.WriteLine()` *after* your `return order;` statement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
foreach (var item in order)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

Or if you have mulitple properties as mentioned above, you can try like this:

```
foreach (var item in order)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Date : {0}, Name : {1}, Adress : {2}",item.Date.ToString(), item.Name.ToString(), item.Adress.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq, as in your second try is close to the actual printing, you just need to format the string properly instead of simply call `ToString` method:

```
order.ForEach(o => Debug.WriteLine("Date: " + o.Date + " Adress: " + o.Adress + "Name: " + o.Name));
```

And I know it is not the point of the question, but I suggest you to use a `ForEach` instruction to populate the list too, as it will add more flexibility to your code.